# What is the difference between sap.m.Title vs. sap.ui.core.Title

Tags: sapui5

What is the main difference between [`sap.ui.core.Title`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Title.html) and  [`sap.m.Title`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Title.html)? Are there specific restrictions, conventions or even [Fiori guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/ui-components/title/#resources) when to use which control?

It looks like sap.m.Title is newer but uses objects from sap.ui.core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `sap.m.Title` when you create a UI5 project via `sap.m` libraries.
`sap.m` libraries are the recommended way to create your UI5 apps because this library is responsive and can run on any device (phone, tablet, desktop etc.)

The `sap.ui.core.Title` was mainly used by the old version of SAP UI5 controls ([`sap.ui.commons`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.html))

So if you go according to the best practices you should go with [`sap.m`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.html) libraries there you need to use `sap.m.Title` control.

Comment: I tried both the controls and couldn't detect any difference in behavior.  I do agree with the usage of sap.m controls for responsiveness.